# Insertion of records failed when tried to insert into table, due to After trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace 
trigger trigger_craftShopItems 
after insert on craftshopitems for each row

declare

user_name varchar2(20);
new_craftId number;
new_craftItemName varchar2(40);
new_CraftVendor  varchar2(40);
new_CraftStoreId number;

begin

  select user into user_name from dual;

  select craftId,craftItemName,CraftVendor,CraftStoreId into new_craftId,new_craftItemName,new_CraftVendor,new_CraftStoreId
  from craftshopitems where rownum =(select max(rownum) from craftshopitems);

  dbms_output.put_line('Insert operation performed by :'||user_name);

  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftID: '|| new_craftId);

  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftItemName: '||new_craftItemName);

  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftVendor: '|| new_CraftVendor);

  dbms_output.put_line('NewCraftStoreId:'|| new_CraftStoreId);  

end trigger_craftShopItems;
```

***********************Error Message*******************

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-04091: table ORA_JSHAH87.CRAFTSHOPITEMS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ORA-06512: at "ORA_JSHAH87.TRIGGER_CRAFTSHOPITEMS", line 13
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ORA_JSHAH87.TRIGGER_CRAFTSHOPITEMS'
> 04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
> *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>            this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>            in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
> *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
> ```

Comment: are you clear (understand ) about error message ?

Comment: @additionster is right. There is a logical error in your code anyway. `select max(rownum)` will not necessarily return your row, but might return any row, which was inserted during  your statement. It is related to error message you're getting. Oracle can not guarantee that your code is deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:NEW` to get the newly inserted data.

```
create or replace 
trigger trigger_craftShopItems 
after insert on craftshopitems for each row

declare

user_name varchar2(20);

begin

  select user into user_name from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('Insert operation performed by :'||user_name);
  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftID: '|| :NEW.craftId);
  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftItemName: '|| :NEW.craftItemName);
  dbms_output.put_line('New CraftVendor: '|| :NEW.CraftVendor);
  dbms_output.put_line('NewCraftStoreId:'|| :NEW.CraftStoreId);  

end trigger_craftShopItems;
```